Clone list but with new smaller class
How to copy ListData to ListSmallData with shorter class with less fields?
Can I make it faster not using foreach loop?
    public class Data {

       private int id;
       private String name;
       private int age;
       private int height;
     }

    public class SmallerData {

       private String name;
       private int age;
    }

    main {
       List<Data> dataList = service.findAll();
       System.out.println("List of Data: " + dataList);

       List<SmallerData> smallerDataList = dataList;
       System.out.println("List of Small Data: " + smallerDataList);
    }
    

I expect output:
List of Data: {id:1, name: John, age: 25, height: 180}
List of Small Data: {name: John, age: 25}


How about Data extends SmallerData

BTW: You not clone the objects, you only assign a reference to smallDataList

Short answer: no.  You will have to loop through the first List somehow.  If the first List is large, you can process its elements in parallel using parallelStream().

Not sure what exactly you are after. A for loop should be fine. If you have a huge list you can try and explore the Stream API.
List<SmallerData> smallerDataList = dataList
    .stream()
    .map(data -> new SmallerData(data.getName(), data.getAge()))
    .toList() ;  // In earlier Java, use .collect(Collectors.toList());



Can I make it faster not using foreach loop?

 Are you asking if there is some way to avoid looping?
There is no way to avoid touching every object in the first list. To construct the new object, we must read each original object’s data. To get each original object, we must loop the collection.
Something like this:
record Person( int id , String name , int age , int height ) { }
record PersonAge( String name , int age ) { }

SequencedCollection < Person > persons =
        List.of (
                new Person ( 1 , "Alice" , 25 , 180 ) ,
                new Person ( 2 , "Bob" , 35 , 160 )
        );

SequencedCollection < PersonAge > personAges = new ArrayList <> ( );

for ( Person person : persons )
{
    personAges.add ( new PersonAge ( person.name , person.age ) );
}

A stream effectively does the same thing as the for loop. A stream too will access each of the objects in the original list. Different syntax, same work to be performed.
List < PersonAge > personAges =
        persons
                .stream ( )
                .map ( ( Person person ) -> new PersonAge ( person.name , person.age ) )
                .toList ( );

 Are you asking if there is some way to accelerate execution?
If on a multi-core machine, then using parallel stream might take less time on the clock. But you would have to have a large enough amount of data to make up for the overhead of setting up and coordinating the multi-threaded workload.
To make your stream parallel, replace .stream with  .parallelStream.
List < PersonAge > personAges =
        persons
                .parallelStream ( )  // ⬅️ Parallelize the stream. 
                .map ( ( Person person ) -> new PersonAge ( person.name , person.age ) )
                .toList ( );

Beware: Parallel stream might well take more time rather than less. Parallelizing streams are not a magic answer to all performance problems, contrary to popular belief. You need to measure to know.

By the way, that word "clone" in your title is unwittingly a poor choice of words. The word clone has a specific meaning in Java. Your situation does not involve Java cloning.

I would consider adding a kind of copy constructor to PersonAge (taking a Person); or some toPersonAge method to Person.
